# How do I tell the arrow pointing to my start state to point from up?

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

I am drawing finite automata in Tex using the tikz automata library. Here is how my figure begins.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 
\node[state,initial] (q_start)   {$q_start$};
```

This creates an initial node. The "start ->" arrow is pointing to the node from the left.

How do I change this direction? I want "start ->" to point at the initial node from the top.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Key `initial where` sets the direction (`above`, `below`, `left`, `right`),
see **24.3 Initial and Accepting States** of the manual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}
\usepackage{amstext}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto]
\node[state,initial,initial where=above,] (q_start)   {$q_\text{start}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]